# Prove that direct sum of torsion module is torsion

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $R$ is a ring and $M$ and $N$ are $R$-module. Prove that

a) If $R$ is integral domain, then $Tor(M \bigoplus N) \cong Tor(M) \bigoplus Tor(N)$

b) If $P$ is a submodule of $M$ and $Q$ is a submodule of $N$, then $M \bigoplus N /P \bigoplus Q \cong M/P \bigoplus N/Q$.

For the first part, I kind of confused of the direct sum. The direct sum here means external direct sum or internal direct sum?

For the second part, I define a map $f: M \bigoplus N \rightarrow M/P \bigoplus N/Q$ where $(m,n) \rightarrow (m+P,n+Q)$

Then I manage to show the map is bijective module homomorphism. Just want to confirm with the surjectivity, is it trivial in this case? Like I have $(m+P,n+Q)$, then its preimage is $(m,n)$ right?

EDIT: Part a): Let $(m,n) \in Tor(M) \bigoplus Tor(N)$. Then there exists $q,s \in R$, where $q,s \neq 0$ such that $(qm,sn)=(0,0)$ Note that since $R$ is integral domain and $q,s \neq 0 \Rightarrow qs \neq 0$. Hence, $qs(m,n)=(qsm,qsn)=(s(qm),q(sn))=(0,0)$, which implies that $(m,n) \in Tor(M \bigoplus N)$

Let $(m,n) \in Tor(M \bigoplus N)$. Then there exists $r \in R,r \neq 0$ such that $r(m,n)=(0,0)=(rm,rn) \Rightarrow rm=0,rn=0 \Rightarrow (m,n) \in Tor(M) \bigoplus Tor(N)$. Hence, $Tor(M \bigoplus N)=Tor(M) \bigoplus Tor(N)$

Answer (score 1):

a) This has to be external direct sum; 'internal' direct sum refers to the case where $M$ and $N$ are given as submodules of some common module.

b) You are right that surjectivity is somewhat trivial.  However, be careful with your wording; $(m,n)$ is *in* the pre-image of $(m+P, n+Q)$, but the pre-image is typically bigger:
$$
f^{-1}(m+P, n+Q) = \{ (m+p, n+q) ~\vert~ p \in P, q \in Q\}
$$

Comment: So to prove part a), I have to define a map and show it is bijective homomorphism?

Comment: Part $a$ is much easier, they are actually equal not just isomorphic since both sides are submodules of $M\oplus N$. One side of the inclusion is simple the other relies on the commutativity of $R$.

Answer (score 1):

We show for part a) that they are equal (since both are submodules of $M\oplus N$).

Take $(m,n)\in \text{Tor}(M\oplus N)$. Then there exists $r\in R$ regular such that $r(m,n) = (0,0)$. But $r(m,n) = (rm,rn)$ by definition and so $m\in\text{Tor}(M)$, similarly for $n$. Thus $(m,n)\in\text{Tor}(M)\oplus\text{Tor}(N)$.

Take $(m,n)\in\text{Tor}(M)\oplus\text{Tor}(N)$. Then there exists regular $r,s\in R$ such that $rm=0$ and $sn=0$. Then by the commutativity of $R$ we see that $rs(m,n)=(0,0)$ and so $(m,n)\in\text{Tor}(M\oplus N)$.

Thus the two submodules are equal.